# Why eclipse "delete" and File "new" will block the UI while waiting, wheraes other jobs which I created won't block but will be in waiting state?

Tags: eclipse

I will schedule some job first for file creation under the  project. (Refering "On the Job: The Eclipse Jobs API" article example.)
Scheduling rule used is job.setRule(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()).This means job will acquire a lock on workspace root itself. And any other operations which I perform like "delete" or File menu "new" project creation will go to waiting state.
But why   eclipse "delete"  or File "new" operation will block my entire UI, wheraes the jobs which I  created  will only  goes to waiting state when   I acquire lock on workspace root?
Can I able to implement my own "delete" operation where like any other jobs will go to waiting state but not block the UI when some other job is  already running and given the same scheduling rule?

Answer (score 0):

The File New and Delete operations don't use the Jobs API but they do wait for access to the workspace so they can block the UI until it is available.

You could write New and Delete operations that use the Jobs API so that the operations run in the background.